# Optimize delete operation on table with millions of records

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with multiple columns. "reason" is one of the non-indexed columns, which may have duplicated values. In my table there are in total two hundred thousand records. I want to delete rows based on a particular reason, for example "MY REASON", whereas there are around 15K records with "MY REASON".

When I use a standard delete query as shown below, it takes too much time (around 3 or 4 hours).

```
delete from my_table where reason='MY REASON';
commit;
```

How can I speed this up?

This is the execution plan for the same:

```
   Plan hash value: 2164670663
   | Id  | Operation          | Name             | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |   0 | DELETE STATEMENT   |                  |  6190 |   175K|  1019   (0)| 10:30:49 |
   |   1 |  DELETE            | MY_TABLE         |       |       |            |          |
   |*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| MY_TABLE         |  6190 |   175K|  1019   (0)| 10:30:49 |
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
   ---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("REASON"='MY REASON')
```

Statistics for 10rows deletion using primary key, id:

```
SQL> set timing on;
SQL> set autotrace on explain statistics;
SQL> delete from my_table where id between 194404 and 194414;

11 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:19.53

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2403087528

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Id  | Operation         | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT  |                   |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:38 |

|   1 |  DELETE           | MY_TABLE          |       |       |            |      |

|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| PK_MY_TABLE       |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:38 |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("id">=194404 AND "id"<=194414)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
         94  recursive calls
         66  db block gets
     602170  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
       8844  redo size
        528  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        372  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          4  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          7  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
         11  rows processed

SQL>
```

***ISSUE FIXED AFTER ADDING INDEX ON CHILD TABLE*****
Below are trace details:

```
AFTER ADDING INDEX TO CHILD TABLE
---------------------------------
SQL> set timing on;
SQL> set autotrace on explain statistics;
SQL> delete from MY_TABLE where id between 194241 and 194361;

121 rows deleted.

Elapsed: 00:00:01.37

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2403087528

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

| Id  | Operation         | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

|   0 | DELETE STATEMENT  |                   |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:38 |

|   1 |  DELETE           | MY_TABLE          |       |       |            |      |

|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN| PK_MY_TABLE       |     1 |    29 |     1   (0)| 00:00:38 |

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("ID">=194241 AND "ID"<=194361)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          3  recursive calls
        760  db block gets
          7  consistent gets
          9  physical reads
      83968  redo size
        527  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        372  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          4  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          5  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
        121  rows processed
```

Comment: Post the execution plan of the delete statement. See this how to generate explain plan http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/05/31/oracle-explain-plan/

Comment: Why dont you add an index over it..

Comment: @LalitKumarB, this is the result:

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar, actually i tried adding index, but i dont see much improvement. I created like this:  CREATE INDEX I_FREASON_IND_TEMP
    ON my_table (f_reason);

Comment: That explain plan is unreadable. Formatting is very important. Edit your question, add the explain plan, and make sure you use code tags.

Comment: Added execution plan in question itself. Actually i was not aware that i need to update it in question. I tried several ways to post the same in comment itself. It dint work out.

Comment: Did you gather statistics after adding the index?

Comment: Using an index scan for resolving the lookup does not make much sense to me, since the number of rows to be deleted (according to the question description) is 15000 ... = potential of 15000 single block reads. Based on the stats it occurs to me that the table is only `175K / 6190 * 200000 = 5.5 MB` big. Full table scan should read this in fragments of a second. I suspect that the troublemaker is the `delete` itself plus indexes and possibly cascading constraints, with all of the undo and redo being saved in the process.

Comment: @Kaluva, please, run the query in SQL*Plus, prepending it with command `set autotrace on explain statistics` (do a rollback after that, better do NOT commit) and post the output to your question text.

Comment: @nop77svk, i'm running the query as mentioned in the article, http://tamilselvang.blogspot.in/2011/11/parallel-delete-on-nonpartitioned-table.html. Once it is over, will run yours and let you know.

Comment: Since you could have 15k rows with the same reason why dont you create a new table for the "reasons" and do an FK relation, this way you would have 15k rows with numeric value and it would be indexed and I assume an operation on such column would be faster than string comparison

Comment: @JafarKofahi, In that table, there is one primary column, ID, which is continuous sequence number. Even if i use it in query like, **delete from my_table where ID between 1020 and 1030**, (just to check for 10 rows), its taking around 18secs. Im not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @JafarKofahi, it does not make much difference, performance-wise. String comparisons are quick enough.

Comment: @kaluva, your recent comment sheds a little more light on your problem. Try running the `delete from my_table where ID between 1020 and 1030` with the SQL*Plus autotrace switched on.

Comment: @nop77svk, done. Added trace details to my question.

Comment: 602170 consistent gets and 94 recursive calls. That just does not seem right.

Comment: A possible answer follows ...

Comment: @BobJarvis *Did you gather statistics after adding the index?* No need to gather statistics after creating index, **[Oracle Database now automatically collects statistics during index creation and rebuild.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5010.htm#sthref6626)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for indexes on columns which are in foreign key constraints. Not just in your `my_table`, but in all of your database. Each foreign key should have its corresponding index on the same set of columns.

Create the missing indexes (with a clearly temporary names, so you can easily drop them afterwards).

Then try running your `delete` again.

Comment: actually i left office and came to home. Will check this tomorrow and update you. Thanks for your efforts, anyways..

Comment: perfect. Thanks for giving me insight into foreign keys. Found the issue finally. There is a child table, my_table_log, where its id is a foreign-key of `my_table`'s id. But in this child table, its not a primary key as it need to have multiple entries, and have total records`2459138`. There is no index also. Now i added index on that column in `my_table_log`. Now it took, `00:00:01.37`, for deleting 121 rows. Added trace details in the question itself just for your information. Thank you very much:)

Answer (score 1):

If the delete is taking many hours as you say you could always try something like this:

1)

```
CREATE TABLE BACK_MY_TABLE AS SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE 
  where reason not in ('MY REASON');
```

2)  `DROP TABLE MY_TABLE`
3)  `ALTER TABLE BACK_MY_TABLE RENAME TO MY_TABLE`

It seems to me initially that there are a lot of indexes getting rebuilt along the way / you are using a bitmap index somewhere.

Additionally, since this is Oracle you can set consumer groups up that enable certain users (such as maybe a cleanup user that runs these delete jobs) to only get X percent of the available resources.  By **DEFAULT** each process tries to get 100% of all resources.  This leads to contention and can drastically impact your performance.

Comment: well the first part is, sure.  The second part is more likely than not what needs to happen.

Comment: hi @Woot4Moo, i'm aware of the solution you suggested. I just wanted to know why i'm not able to perform on the same table and any solution for that. Moreover, i need to execute this in production db if required. There i can't drop and recreate table for various reasons.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, yes, you're right. Apologies for my rather rude behaviour. The consumer groups you mention are an interesting additional dimension of performance-influencers in Oracle, haven't heard of them yet and will check them out. Thank you.